# Operator[][] overload - to change the value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a `matrix` class and wish to do this operation:

```
matrix m1(2,4);     //creates matrix of size 2,4 full of 1's
m1[1][2]=4;         //I wish the value in place m1- row 1 col 2 will be 4
```

this is example to how my code is writen (found on this site ty Seth Carnegie!!)

```
class matrix{
public:
    matrix() {
        _arrayofarrays = new int*[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            _arrayofarrays[i] = new int[10];
    }

    class Proxy {
    public:
        Proxy(int* _array) : _array(_array) { }

        int operator[](int index) {
            return _array[index];
        }
    private:
        int* _array;
    };

    Proxy operator[](int index) {
        return Proxy(_arrayofarrays[index]);
    }

private:
    int** _arrayofarrays;
};
```

the problem is : m1[2][4] returns a int and offcorce if i chage the returned value it does not change the m1 value

how can I do it so the value will be changed? (maybe return int& or something?)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Please, take a look at [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-array-of-array).

Answer (score 1):

return `int&` instead of `int`